# Trying to run my code and compiler seems to just close after it executes

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a program and the compiler seems to just crash right after it executes ... I have no build errors.

I have tried commenting out blocks of code and still to no avail. I have copied the main also into another file and ran it and it worked .... so I really stumped.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   public class Student
{

string Fname, Lname, Program ;
int Sid ;

// Inputting information for students
public void InputStudentInfo () 
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Please enter your first name") ;
    Fname = Console.ReadLine() ;
    Console.WriteLine ("Please enter you last name") ;
    Lname = Console.ReadLine() ;
    Console.WriteLine ("Please enter you student ID#") ;
    Sid = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) ;
    Console.WriteLine ("Enter the Program that you are completeing") ;
    Program = Console.ReadLine() ;
}

// Printing information for students
public void PrintStudentInfo ()
{
    Console.Write (" Your name is " + Fname) ;
    Console.Write(" " + Lname);
    Console.WriteLine (" Your student identification number is " + Sid) ;
    Console.WriteLine (" The program you are registered for is " + Program) ;
} 

/* public void MenuInterface()
{
    Console.WriteLine (" 1. Input Student information" ) ;
    Console.WriteLine (" 2. Input Course information" ) ;
    Console.WriteLine (" 3. Input Grade information" ) ;
    Console.WriteLine (" 4. Print Course information" ) ;
    Console.WriteLine (" 5. Print Student information" ) ;
    Console.WriteLine (" 6. Print Grade information" ) ;
    Console.WriteLine (" 7. Print Student information including Course they are registered in and the grade obtained for that course" ) ;
    Console.WriteLine (" 8. Print grade info of the course in which student has achieved the highest grade" ) ;
    Console.WriteLine (" 0. Exit") ;
    Console.WriteLine (" Please select a choice from 0-8") ;
    accode = Console.ReadLine();
} */

}

public class Course
{

string course1, course2, course3 ;
int Stuid ;

// Inputting Course Information
public void InputCourseInfo ()
{
    Console.WriteLine (" Please re-enter your identification number") ;
    Stuid = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) ;
    Console.WriteLine (" Enter the name of your first course") ;
    course1 = Console.ReadLine() ;
    Console.WriteLine (" Enter the name of your second course") ;
    course2 = Console.ReadLine() ;
    Console.WriteLine (" Enter the name of your third course") ;
    course3 = Console.ReadLine() ;
}

// Printing Course Information
public void PrintCourseInfo ()
{
    Console.WriteLine (" Your ID # is " + Stuid) ;
    Console.Write (" The Courses you selected are " + course1) ;
    Console.Write("," + course2);
    Console.Write(" and " + course3);
}
}
public class Grade : Course
{
    int Studentid ; 
    int [] hwgrade ; 
    int [] cwgrade ;
    int [] midegrade ; 
    int [] finalegrade ; 
    int [] totalgrade ;
    string coursename ;

    public Grade ( string cname , int Studentident , int [] homework , int [] classwork , int [] midexam , int [] finalexam)
    {
        coursename = cname ;
        Studentid = Studentident ;  
        hwgrade = homework ;
        cwgrade = classwork ;
        midegrade = midexam ;
        finalegrade = finalexam ;
    } 

    public string coname
    {
        get
        {
            return coursename ;
        }
        set
        {
            coursename = value ;
        }
    }

    public int Studentidenty
    {
        get
        {
            return Studentid ;
        }
        set
        {
            Studentid = value ;
        }
    }

    public void InputGradeInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine (" Please enter your Student ID" ) ;
        grade.Studentidenty = Console.ReadLine() ;
        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.Writeline (" Please enter the Course name" ) ;
            grade.coname[i] = Console.Readline() ;
            Console.Writeline (" Please enter your homework grade") ;
            grade.hwgrade[i] = int.parse(Console.Readline()) ;
           // .....
        }
    }

    public void CalcTotalGrade()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            grade.courseper[i] = (grade.hwgrade[i] + grade.cwgrade[i]) / 2;
            grade.finalper[i] = (grade.midexam[i] + grade.finalegrade[i]) / 2;
            grade.totalgrade[i] = (grade.courseper[i] + finalper[i]) / 2;
        }
    }

    public void PrintGradeInfo()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.Writeline (" Your homework grade is" + grade.hwgrade[i]) ;
           // .....
        }
    }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int accode ;
            Student student = new Student() ;
            Course course = new Course() ;
            Grade grade = new Grade() ;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" 1.  Input Student information");
                Console.WriteLine(" 2.  Input Course information");
                Console.WriteLine(" 3.  Input Grade information");
                Console.WriteLine(" 4.  Print Course information");
                Console.WriteLine(" 5.  Print Student information");
                Console.WriteLine(" 6.  Print Grade information");
                Console.WriteLine(" 7.  Print Student information including Course they are registered in and the grade obtained for that course");
                Console.WriteLine(" 8.  Print grade info of the course in which student has achieved the highest grade");
                Console.WriteLine(" 0.  Exit");
                Console.WriteLine(" Please select a choice from 0-8");
                accode = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (accode)
                {
                    case 1:
                        student.InputStudentInfo();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        course.InputCourseInfo();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        grade.InputGradeInfo();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        course.PrintCourseInfo();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        student.PRintStudentInfo();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        grade.PrintGradeInfo();
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine(" You have chosen to exit the program have a good day. =)");
                        break;
                }
            } while (accode != 0); 
            Console.ReadKey();
        } 
    }
}
```

In terms of when i said that i copied the main ... I mean that i took all code that was under the main and opened a new project and placed the code back , and the program ran. I tried the suggestion about using try and catch ... but the same problem still occurs that when i press start , there are no errors , the cmd opens and closes in a split second. when i press ctrl + f5 the screen comes up but only says 'press any key to continue'.

Comment: Your code won't compile - you're trying to assign a `string` value from `Console.ReadLine()` to an `int` variable.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is catch the exceptions that happen when `int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() )` fails when it attempts to parse non-integer string.  The second thing you need to do is just read in strings.  There is no reason that `Sid` needs to be an integer.  Once you attempt to debug the problem yourself we might be able to help you.  Your exact question is not clear, your program really does nothing, you don't even tell us what is not working.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by this " I have copied the main also into another file and ran it and it worked .... so I really stumped." just do this!

Answer (score 3):

Put a try catch in your main method like this to give you a hint as to what is wrong:

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
            {  
    try
    {
                int accode ;  
                Student student = new Student() ;  
                Course course = new Course() ;  
                Grade grade = new Grade() ;  
                do  
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine(" 1.  Input Student information");  
...
                    Console.WriteLine(" 0.  Exit");  
                    Console.WriteLine(" Please select a choice from 0-8");  
                    accode = Console.ReadLine();  
                    switch (accode)  
                    {
    ...  
                    }  
                } while (accode != 0);   
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
       Console.Writeline("Exception: " + ex.Message);
    }
                Console.ReadKey();  
            }
```